# Proof of Equivalence of Least Squares Problem

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces, least-squares, equivariant-topology

Let $b \in \mathbb R^n $ and $A \in \mathbb R^{m\times n}$ with $m \geqslant n$ and $\operatorname{rank}(A)\le n$. 
Prove that the following statements are equivalent;

1. $\hat{x} = \operatorname{argmin}_{x \in \mathbb R^n} \|Ax-b\|^2$
2. $A^t(b-A  \hat{x})=0$.

---

I know that;
$$
\|Ax-b\|^2
= (Ax-b)^t(Ax-b)
= x^tA^tAx-2x^tA^tb+b^2.
$$
Which can simplify to;
$$
A^t(Ax-b)
=0
$$

However I am still really confused if this is right and provides a full detailed proof of the equivalent please!

Comment: How does the **expression** $x^T A^T A x - 2 x^T A^T b + b^2$ simplify to **equation** $A^T (A x - b) = 0$?

Comment: The argmin is unique only if the columns of $A$ are linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** One approach is to calculate the derivative of $\| A x - b \|^2$, set it to zero and solve for $\hat{x}$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
& \|Ax-b\|^2 \\[8pt]
= {} & \|(Ax-Ay) + (Ay - b)\|^2 \\[8pt]
= {} & \|Ax-Ay\|^2 + \|Ay - b\|^2 + 2(Ax-Ay)^t (Ay - b) \\[8pt]
= {} & \|Ax-Ay\|^2 + \|Ay - b\|^2 + 2(x-y)^t A^t (Ay - b)
\end{align}
If the vector $y$ is one for which $A^t(Ay-b)=0,$ then  the last line above is
$$
\|Ax-Ay\|^2 + \|Ay-b\|^2.
$$
If $x=y$ then the first term above vanishes and thereby makes the sum as small as possible. If the columns of $A$ are linearly independent, then the only such value of $x$ is $y;$ otherwise $y$ is one value of the argmin and there are others.

In other words, any value of $y$ that makes $A^t(Ay-b)=0$ is a value of $\operatorname{argmin}_x \|Ax-b\|^2.$